# mysql.data 8.0 occurs "Parameter '-' not found in the collection" in .net core 3.1 when call PROCEDURE

Tags: c#, mysql

mysql.data 8.0 occurs "Parameter '-' not found in the collection" in .net core 3.1 when call PROCEDURE.But it ok when I make "CheckParameters=false".But I don't want CheckParameters to be false.

my enviranment is :

asp.net core 3.1
mysql.data in installed from nuget and the version is 8.0.20
the database is in cloud of tencent and is

my sp code is :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_Sys_Option_Select_Test`(
    IN  INKEYWORD               VARCHAR(50),        --  关键字
    IN  INPAGESIZE              VARCHAR(50),            --  每页行数
    IN  INCURPAGE               VARCHAR(50),            --  当前页数
    IN  USERCODE                    VARCHAR(50),        --  操作人编码       (*)
    OUT OUTTOTALCOUNT       VARCHAR(50),            --  总行数
    OUT OUTCHECKMESSAGE VARCHAR(500)        --  返回消息
)
BEGIN 
    select now() as dttime;
    SET OUTTOTALCOUNT = 'this is out_TotalCount';
    SET OUTCHECKMESSAGE = 'Y:控制开关查询成功(反馈';
END
```

and my c# in asp.net core 3.1 is :

```
using (var conn= new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("sp_Sys_Option_Select_Test", conn);
    myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "INKEYWORD", Value = "", Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, DbType = System.Data.DbType.String });
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "INPAGESIZE", Value = "2", Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, DbType = System.Data.DbType.String });
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "INCURPAGE", Value = "1", Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, DbType = System.Data.DbType.String });
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "USERCODE", Value = "ADMIN", Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, DbType = System.Data.DbType.String });
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "OUTTOTALCOUNT", Value = null, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, DbType = System.Data.DbType.String, Size = 4000 });
    var outp = new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "OUTCHECKMESSAGE", Value = null, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, DbType = System.Data.DbType.String, Size = 4000 };
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(outp);
    MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    mda.Fill(ds);
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(outp.Value));
}
```

you can see my parameters without '@'.Actually,it is then same error when I add '@' to the parameter.
then the exception is :

```
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection.GetParameterFlexible(String parameterName, Boolean throwOnNotFound)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.GetAndFixParameter(String spName, MySqlSchemaRow param, Boolean realAsFloat, MySqlParameter returnParameter)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.CheckParameters(String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.Resolve(Boolean preparing)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at EcCloudCoreApi.Program.CreateHostBuilder(String[] args) in
```

Comment: You show a SP named _sp_Sys_Option_Select_Test_ but you call _sp_Sys_Option_Select_

Comment: @Steve Sorry,I wrote too many verions of the code when I test it.So I copied error code.I modified the question

Comment: @jdweng I modified my question and select in the sp.But the error exists.

Comment: I can't reproduce a problem with your code. However, there are known bugs with executing stored procedures with MySql.Data (e.g., https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96143). Does it fix the bug if you switch to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ ?

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Yes, it fix the bug if I switch to nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector

Comment: @ensleep I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in Oracle's MySQL Connector/NET (i.e., `MySql.Data`). If you can find a small repro, you can report it at https://bugs.mysql.com. (I wasn't able to reproduce the problem with the code you provided, using MySQL Server.)

You should be able to work around the problem by switching to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), an alternate MySQL ADO.NET library. Instructions for migrating are here: https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/

Comment: I found the answer.When I remove "     --  关键字" ,the errors gone!!! How???Oh,My God.